# How can I import Garmin Pilot checklist files into ForeFlight?

Tags: flight-planning, checklist

Inside the airplane that I am training on, there is an iPad running the Garmin Pilot app with all the checklists for that plane in the app as a "Checklist Binder". I use my own iPad (a second iPad) on a kneeboard with ForeFlight for my sectional charts, flight planning, weather, TFRs, NOTAMs, PIREPs, AIRMETs, METARs, and everything else.

I was able to export the checklist binder from Garmin Pilot as a `.gplts` file from the iPad (the one that lives in the plane I am renting) and email it to myself. On my iPad, I was able to download the Garmin Pilot app and import the checklist binder really easily.

I'd like to export/import these checklists (this checklist binder) into my ForeFlight app so that all of my relevant information can be in the same place. Does anyone know a straightforward way to do this?

Currently, I have ForeFlight and Garmin Pilot on my iPad and I have to switch between them, which is a lot better than having to sit one iPad on top of the other when I need to go through a checklist. But I'd really like to be able to move these checklists into ForeFlight and keep everything in the same application.

Comment: Just a thought: Garmin Pilot does show weather, TFRs, etc., so you could just switch to it.

Answer (score 2):

I posed a similar question to ForeFlight in May 2021 (how to import my text checklists to FF) and there reply was that import is not supported - here is their reply (and I never received any follow up indicating they were considering it further)

> Currently, there is not a way to way to import checklists at this time. The only workaround that you could do in the meantime is upload your checklist to documents as a pdf. It won't be saved in the checklists section but would be in your EFB.

> We appreciate the feature request though and I will pass your request on to our Product Management team for their consideration.

Comment: Bummer... Hopefully, they get to it soon, won't hold my breath. Thanks for your answer!